# Visual Studio Team Services REST API with curl

Tags: curl, tfs, libcurl

I can access Team Services API with Google's DHC Extension or in code but can't achieve the same with curl.

so far I've tried:

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://MYINSTANCE.VisualStudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0

i'm keep getting "Object moved to ...." result.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Tried `-L` or `--location` ?

Comment: yes, i've even tried like this: curl -c mk.txt -L -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://MYINSTANCE.VisualStudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met this issue before and get it work by changing "**Bearer**" to "**Basic**".

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic <TOKEN>" https://xxxxxx.VisualStudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0
```

**Update:**
Current, VSO Rest API only support Basic authentication and Authorize access with OAuth 2.0. You'd either use Basic Auth or use curl to fetch OAuth2.0 access token from VSO. Refer to this link for details: [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth).

And I just tried DHC with personal access token, but get following message: "We are sorry, but Chrome API does not allow to get a response body for redirect." So you may need to clear your browser cookies and caches and then try to see if bearer can works with VSO Rest API in DHC.

Comment: I've just tested with the Basic but i'm still getting the same "Object moved" resut.

Comment: @mkazanova How do you generate the access token? I get it by clicking "set an authorization" in DHC and enter my Alternate authentication credentials with "Basic" type selected.

Comment: in DHC it even works with Bearer, it doesn't work with curl command line. Created the token, Under my profile's security tab by adding a new Personal Access Token.

Comment: @mkazanova I thought you are using the token generated by Basic Auth. Sorry for the misunderstand. Due to the comments limitation, I add my detailed comments in answer, please refer to it for details.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the fine manual here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1

And you can format your curl request as follows (the following example is for retrieving your VSTS builds):

```
curl -u username:PATtoekn -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://your-account.visualstudio.com/your-project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1 -k
```

Good luck!

Comment: This did the job for me. Thank you.