# Unable to name release(yaml) pipeline with custom variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have release pipeline configured which gets triggered by pipeline resources(build). i set some custom variables based on build pipelines,  trying to  update with release pipeline with build pipeline infos.

below is the my release pipeline code:

```
            resources:
            pipelines:
            - pipeline: pipeline1
              project: appcom
              source: pipeline-api
              trigger:
                branches:
                - develop
                - feat/*
            -  pipeline: pipeline2
               project: appcom
               source: pipeline2-api
               trigger:
               branches:
               - develop
               - feat/*

          variables:
          - name: alias
            value: $(resources.triggeringAlias)
          stages:
          - stage: ScanImage
            jobs:
            - job: ScanImage
               pool:
                 vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
               steps:
               - script: echo $(alias)

               - task: Bash@3
                 inputs:
                 targetType: 'inline'
                   script: |
                    if [ "$(alias)" == "pipeline1" ]; then
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable 
                    variable=apiname]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.pipelineName)"
                    fi
                - script: echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$(apiname)"
```

when  pipeline get executed it says tag is created as shown in below picture
[image]
when i go and try to filter with tag, it says no tags  as below image
[image]

any idea on this ?a

Comment: If you select the first run that you think should have the tag, does it appear within the job details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to name release(yaml) pipeline with custom variables

The tag is not displayed on the summary of the build definition directly, but we could use the filter with tag to list which pipelines contain the specified tags:

[image]

If you want check the tag directly, you need open one build pipeline:

[image]

Or you could use the REST API [Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to check the tag info:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=6.0
```

[image]

**Note:** The tag was added to the build Id **614011**, you should make sure you check the correct pipeline.

Comment: when i try to filter with tags, its says no tags as mentioned in screenshot.
also is it possible to change pipeline description with variable called $(apiname) in my case ?
i am looking any one of these solutions

Comment: @pranathi, If you want to update the pipeline description with variable called `$(apiname)`, you could use the REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0  in your pipeline to update the description.

Comment: can i get some bash script sample for this to add on my pipeline ?

Comment: also i cannot  use PAT in my Organization

Comment: @pranathi, The answer is yes, you could use REST API with curl. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648868/visual-studio-team-services-rest-api-with-curl and use the Invoke REST API task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops. If you could not use the PAT, you could use `system.token`

Comment: thanks.   i just used echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$(apiname)" it is setting up tag but when i tried click to tags to filter , it simply says no tags avaiable